# Can I still upload an application that does not support iOS8+?

Tags: ios7, ios8, appstore-approval, ios7.1

Can I still upload an application that does not support iOS8+?

I currently have an app that we are releasing for iOS7 and 7.1, but it was rejected because it was not compatible for iOS8.

We are currently in the process of building the iOS8 version, but wanted to release something quickly.

Comment: "*Can I still upload an application that does not support iOS8+?*" "*it was rejected because it was not compatible for iOS8.*" Why doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: To put it simply, it doesn't.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple App Store policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. I'm not sure the exact date that apple made it mandatory to support iOS 8 but I do know it has passed so any new apps/updates submitted to the app store need to support iOS 8.

Comment: Do you know where I can find an official statement from Apple around this? It's so weird that it wasn't 'announced' for developers.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to build & submit it with XCode 6, iOS SDK 8.0.

They may reject if the app doesn't work with iOS 8. Do a quick test to make sure it doesn't crash, and all major functions are working fine.

Comment: So we actually do need a build which is working on iOS8. We were under the impression you could still submit iOS7 applications.